# Weird pixels on the title screen on Windows 10

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I got a new computer with Windows 10 and I downloaded Minecraft (Vanilla). I have always had it on my computer but for some reason it looks like this:

[image: Title screen with pixels shifted everywhere]

What should I do?

Comment: Try updating your graphics drivers.

Comment: Seems to be the case, yeah. Then maybe it'd be a good idea to actually use the Win10 edition? Seeing as a lot of games have trouble with compatibility when Microsoft releases a new OS.

Comment: @P1raten The windows 10 edition is not compatible with the PC version, it is closer related to the pocket edition of Minecraft. So there may be a reason they are using the PC edition

Comment: Have you been paid a visit by Cthulhu or something?

Answer (score 2):

This could be lots of things. Some of the things I would try are:

- Un-installing and re-installing: This will refresh the package and maybe fix any coding errors the game has that makes it do this.  Windows 10 might have messed some of the code-up, so a re-install could fix this.
- Update your graphics drivers: Similar to the one above, after you updated to Windows 10 your graphics drivers may have become out of date and need updating to support certain games on new systems. You can achieve this by going into your driver settings and clicking "update" (It may be different for different drivers).
- Contact Mojang/Microsoft: They might have some ideas as to what the problem might be; contacting the publishers is always a good idea as it may lead them to fix it and stop anybody else in the future getting it!

Hope this helps! If it's not any of these then I'm sorry but I can't help you.

*Source: Past expierience*